# Apache HttpClient 4.3.x has no default host?

Tags: apache-httpclient-4.x

HttpClient 4.3.x issue.

There does not seem to be a way to attach a default host on CloseableHttpClient for 4.3.x.

This is frustrating as it requires all of your request builders to know up front all the host info, rather than just building up the request parts specific to the call and letting the client fill in any left out defaults (eg. like a default host, port, etc).

With 4.2.x and previous, you could set the default host on the client and any request just needs a subpath + parameters.

But with 4.3.x you have confusing layers of setRoutePlanner(x) (which could have proxy settings) and setProxy(x) (which could be overridden by route-planner) and I'm confused how they settle with the actual client instance.  And debugging it shows that route-planner will not get used for default_host, and the 4.3.2 version actually expects the deprecated ClientPNames.DEFAULT_HOST to be set (for case with null target host) which is maybe a defect.

I am finding apache httpclient to be going off a deep edge with all these changes.

Also the examples do not fully clarify http client usage unfortunately.

As an aside: the new design is such mud, why not just have setDefaultHost(x) ? and clear up the confusion on proxy layering(s).

Unless I'm missing something, how does one set the default host in http client 4.3.x?

Why do you think they changed and decided to make everything up front in the request objects vs. defaults in the client?

Comment: "And debugging it shows that route-planner will not get used for default_host, and the 4.3.2 version actually expects the deprecated ClientPNames.DEFAULT_HOST to be set (for case with null target host) which is maybe a defect" This is indeed a defect. Null target should be perfectly legal as an input to a route planner. Please raise a JIRA with the project for this defect

Comment: thanks for that.  generally, why has the httpclient project decided to externalize so much of the client in a way that requires holding all these parts/pieces ?  its great to have all these components to override, but its not good to have to hold refs all around in order to build up request objects vs. setting attributes on the client and letting it hydrate the request object with defaults.

Comment: Given the sentiment of your post, I doubt anything I have to say would make any difference.

Answer (score 2):

This how one can provide a default target host using a custom route planner

```
HttpRoutePlanner routePlanner = new DefaultRoutePlanner(DefaultSchemePortResolver.INSTANCE) {

    @Override
    public HttpRoute determineRoute(
            final HttpHost target,
            final HttpRequest request,
            final HttpContext context) throws HttpException {
        return super.determineRoute(
                target != null ? target : new HttpHost("some.default.host", 80),
                request, context);
    }

};
CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.custom()
        .setRoutePlanner(routePlanner)
        .build();
```

Comment: For me, and this is knowing nothing of future httpclient plans, but the above is so verbose to accomplish simple default-host setting on the client, which I bet if you looked at your customers you would find default-host like 90%+ of the time, so now they have to do mixins for  that ... when they have no interest in the ability to "switch" hosts on the fly.

Comment: In the days of HC 3.x parameters used to be added for no good reasons (often because some individual managed to have generated enough noise on the mailing list) due to inherent limitations of the component architecture. Introduction of new parameters was the only way to customize behaviour of many HC core components. As a result HC 3.x end up having several dozens of parameters most of which were completely irrelevant outside a very specific application context. Sadly enough, HC 4.0 largely inherited 3.x preference APIs (for various reasons) with all those marginally useful parameters.

Comment: Continued:  HC 4.3 offers only a limited number of parameters that are generic and appliable to various application contexts. One can still custmozie HttpClient behavior by injecting custom implementations of handler or strategy interfaces. Default target host is a good example of something that should have never been used as a config parameter in the first place.

Comment: This answer should be accepted, as it solves the default host problem.